# Issue? selecting data between_time from DataFrame in pandas 0.17.1

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an issue selecting data from a pandas DataFrame with between_time.  When the start and end dates of the query are between two days the result is empty.  I am using pandas 0.17.1 (python 2.7)

I have the following data frame:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'azi': {Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:00:14.348000'): 109.801,
Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:00:36.125000'): 109.994,
Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:00:57.599000'): 109.60299999999999,
Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:01:14.576000'): 100.2},
'ele': {Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:00:14.348000'): 180.001,
Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:00:36.125000'): 179.999,
Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:00:57.599000'): 179.999,
Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:01:14.576000'): 180.001}})
```

Which results in:

```
                            azi     ele
2015-05-12 00:00:14.348     109.801     180.001
2015-05-12 00:00:36.125     109.994     179.999
2015-05-12 00:00:57.599     109.603     179.999
2015-05-12 00:01:14.576     100.200     180.001
```

The following query **fails**:

```
mydf['azi'].between_time(datetime(2015, 5, 11, 23, 59, 59, 850000), datetime(2015, 5, 12, 0, 1, 59, 850000))
```

resulting in:

```
Series([], Name: azi, dtype: float64)
```

However the following query **works**:

```
mydf2['azi'].between_time(datetime(2015, 5, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2015, 5, 12, 0, 1, 59, 850000))
```

with the right answer:

```
 2015-05-12 00:00:14.348    109.801
 2015-05-12 00:00:36.125    109.994
 2015-05-12 00:00:57.599    109.603
 2015-05-12 00:01:14.576    100.200
 Name: azi, dtype: float64
```

**Questions**:

1. I am missing something in the functionality of the function, or is this a real bug?
2. Is there a workaround for this? The background is that I really need to process data in 1 minute chunks which limits are not always coinciding with 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc-string says it all.

`between_time` selects all TIMES.

```
In [67]: mydf.between_time?
Signature: mydf.between_time(start_time, end_time, include_start=True, include_end=True)
Docstring:
Select values between particular times of the day (e.g., 9:00-9:30 AM)

Parameters
----------
start_time : datetime.time or string
end_time : datetime.time or string
include_start : boolean, default True
include_end : boolean, default True

Returns
-------
values_between_time : type of caller
File:      ~/pandas/pandas/core/generic.py
Type:      instancemethod

In [68]: mydf
Out[68]: 
                             azi      ele
2015-05-12 00:00:14.348  109.801  180.001
2015-05-12 00:00:36.125  109.994  179.999
2015-05-12 00:00:57.599  109.603  179.999
2015-05-12 00:01:14.576  100.200  180.001

In [70]: mydf.between_time('00:00:30','00:01:00')
Out[70]: 
                             azi      ele
2015-05-12 00:00:36.125  109.994  179.999
2015-05-12 00:00:57.599  109.603  179.999
```

You can separately use `partial-string` indexing, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing) to select based on dates (these can be strings or datetimelikes).

```
In [73]: mydf.loc['20150512 00:00:30':'20150512 00:01:00']
Out[73]: 
                             azi      ele
2015-05-12 00:00:36.125  109.994  179.999
2015-05-12 00:00:57.599  109.603  179.999
```

I think `.between_time` should actually raise on non `.time`/ string convertible objects, but IIRC this was done for ease of implementation.

Comment: Your loc solution with @Anton's improvement solved my issue. I think your point about raising an error or a warning is a must. This is quite misleading since it does work with datetimes but **not always**.  In fact I experienced this error just once after having already processed several weeks of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could find a lot of information how to work with datetime index from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#datetimeindex). For you case you could try `loc`:

```
In [147]: mydf['azi'].loc[datetime(2015, 5, 11, 23, 59, 59, 850000): datetime(2015, 5, 12, 0, 1, 59, 850000)]
Out[147]: 
2015-05-12 00:00:14.348    109.801
2015-05-12 00:00:36.125    109.994
2015-05-12 00:00:57.599    109.603
2015-05-12 00:01:14.576    100.200
Name: azi, dtype: float64
```

It was about your 2) bullet. About 1) you could see explanation from @Jeff